# How to do a non-greedy match in grep?

Tags: regex, shell, command-line, grep, regex-greedy

I want to grep the shortest match and the pattern should be something like:

```
<car ... model=BMW ...>
...
...
...
</car>
```

... means any character and the input is multiple lines.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 387, accepted):

You're looking for a non-greedy (or lazy) match. To get a non-greedy match in regular expressions you need to use the modifier `?` after the quantifier. For example you can change `.*` to `.*?`.

By default `grep` doesn't support non-greedy modifiers, but you can use `grep -P` to use the Perl syntax.

Comment: "You will also need the dot all modifier so that the dot matches new lines."  This answer is the top result for "grep dot all modifier" ... what is it?

Comment: eegg: dot all modifier is also known as multiline. It's a modifier that changes the "." match behavior to include newlines (normally it doesn't). There's no such modifier in grep, but there is in [pcregrep](http://linuxcommand.gds.tuwien.ac.at/man_pages/pcregrep1.html).

Comment: Correction: In most of the regex flavors that support it, the mode that allows `.` to match newlines is called *DOTALL* or *single-line* mode; Ruby is the only one that calls it *multiline*.  In the other flavors, *multiline* is the mode that allows the anchors (`^` and `$`) to match at line boundaries.  Ruby has no equivalent mode because in Ruby they always work that way.

Comment: `-P` was a complete new one on me, I've been happily grepping away for years, and only using `-E` ... so many wasted years! - Note to self: Re-read Man pages as a (even more!) regular thing, you never digest enough switches and options.

Comment: On some platforms (like Mac OS X) `grep` does not support `-P`, but if you use `egrep` you can use the `.*?` pattern to achieve the same result. `egrep -o 'start.*?end' text.html`

Comment: As an extension to @SaltyNuts comment, Mac OS X does not support `-P` but `-E` would call `egrep` hence the suggested `.*?` works just fine.

Comment: This answer and comments have so much useful info. Thanks.

Comment: I can't tell the difference of using `.*` or `.*?`, until I use the `-o` option

Comment: `man grep` says: `This is highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.` Why not use Perl itself? Something like `perl -ne 'print if /match/'`

Comment: This worked perfectly on OSX but sadly doesn't (fails silently - continues to greedy match) on alpine linux alpine:3.7. Does anyone know of an alternative?

Comment: I use MacOS. I have both `grep` and `ggrep` (ggrep installed with Homebrew). 
By running these 4 commands, you can see why I prefer using `ggrep -P` vs `grep -E`. `echo "part_1:part_2:" | grep -E '^.*?:' --color=always`, 
`echo "part_1:part_2:" | grep -E -o '^.*?:' --color=always`, 
`echo "part_1:part_2:" | ggrep -P '^.*?:' --color=always`, 
`echo "part_1:part_2:" | ggrep -P -o '^.*?:' --color=always`.

Answer (score 97):

Actualy the `.*?` only works in `perl`. I am not sure what the equivalent grep extended regexp syntax would be. Fortunately you can use perl syntax with grep so `grep -P` would work but `grep -E` which is same as `egrep` would not work (it would be greedy).

See also: http://blog.vinceliu.com/2008/02/non-greedy-regular-expression-matching.html

Comment: `grep -P` does not work in GNU grep 2.9 -- just tried it (it doesnt error, just silently doesn't apply the `?`. Intertestly neither does the *not class* eg: `env|grep '[^\=]*\='`

Comment: There's no `grep -P` option or `pgrep` command in Darwin/OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion, but `egrep` works great.

Comment: There's a `pgrep` command on my OS X 10.9 box, but it's a completely different program whose purpose is to "find or signal processes by name".

Comment: @robertotomás Responding to a 6-year old comment here, but....I thought this as well and then realized I was getting multiple non-greedy matches.  For instance, on a color terminal you can see that ` echo "bbbbb" | grep -P 'b.*?b'` returns 2 matches.

Comment: In 2023 on macOS Monterey 12.6 `grep -E` worked, made it so it uses the perl regex format.

Answer (score 23):

#### `grep`

For non-greedy match in `grep` you could use a negated character class. In other words, try to avoid wildcards.

For example, to fetch all links to jpeg files from the page content, you'd use:

```
grep -o '"[^" ]\+.jpg"'
```

To deal with multiple line, pipe the input through `xargs` first. For performance, use [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep).

Comment: Never thought use it like this. Works for me.

Answer (score 22):

My grep that works after trying out stuff in this thread:

```
echo "hi how are you " | grep -shoP ".*? "
```

Just make sure you append a space to each one of your lines

(Mine was a line by line search to spit out words)

Comment: `-shoP` nice mnemonic :)

Comment: `echo "bbbbb" | grep -shoP 'b.*?b'` is a little bit of a learning experience.  Only thing that worked for me in terms of explicitly lazy as well.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry I am 9 years late, but this might work for the viewers in 2020.

So suppose you have a line like `"Hello my name is Jello"`.
Now you want to find the words that start with `'H'` and end with `'o'`, with any number of characters in between. And we don't want lines we just want words. So for that we can use the expression:

```
grep "H[^ ]*o" file
```

This will return all the words. The way this works is that: It will allow all the characters instead of space character in between, this way we can avoid multiple words in the same line.

Now you can replace the space character with any other character you want.
Suppose the initial line was `"Hello-my-name-is-Jello"`, then you can get words using the expression:

```
grep "H[^-]*o" file
```

Comment: This is merely a regurgitation of kenorb's answer from 2015.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is using the next regular expression:

```
(?s)<car .*? model=BMW .*?>.*?</car>
```

- (?s) - this makes a match across multiline
- .*? - matches any character, a number of times in a lazy way (minimal
  match)

A (little) more complicated answer is:

```
(?s)<([a-z\-_0-9]+?) .*? model=BMW .*?>.*?</\1>
```

This will makes possible to match car1 and car2 in the following text

```
<car1 ... model=BMW ...>
...
...
...
</car1>
<car2 ... model=BMW ...>
...
...
...
</car2>
```

- (..) represents a capturing group
- \1 in this context matches the sametext as most recently matched by
  capturing group number 1

Comment: You are using multiple Perl-style regex extensions which are not available in plain `grep`

Answer (score -2):

I know that its a bit of a dead post but I just noticed that this works. It removed both clean-up and cleanup from my output.

```
> grep -v -e 'clean\-\?up'
> grep --version grep (GNU grep) 2.20
```

Comment: This seems like an answer to another, trivial, question.