# "eager" regexp matching

Tags: regex, perl

I have to remove the string between two delimiters, i.e
From "123XabcX321" I want "123321".
For a simple case, I'm fine with:

```
$_=<>;
s/X(.*)X//;
print;
```

But if there's ambiguity in the input like "123XabcXasdfjXasdX321", it matches the first X with the last X and I get "123321" but I want "123asdfj321". 
Is there a way to specify an "eager" match that matches with the first valid possible delimiter and not the last?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's normally called "ungreedy", you put a ? after the quantifier: `s/X(.*?)X//;`

Comment: and in the example given, /g would be needed to substitute more than once.

Comment: I think "non-greedy" is the more common term.  At any rate, the default is greedy matching, and you want the opposite.

Comment: Note that in Gnu `grep` you'll need to use `--perl-regexp` (`-P`) for the lazy operator (or use the approach below). [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027518/non-greedy-grep)

Comment: Be aware of this: `"XaXbXY" =~ /X(.*?)XY/` => `aXb`

Comment: @ikegami: Aware of what, it working exactly as it's supposed to?

Comment: Be aware that this solution is extremely fragile. It's practically impossible to use it in a large pattern; a million different tiny changes can break it since adding `?` doesn't prevent `.*` from matching anything.

Comment: It's not at all fragile, you just need to understand how it works so you're not making incorrect assumptions. BTW, consider `/X(?>(.*?)X)Y/` if you really want X as a delimiter while still having the extra Y suffix in there too.

Answer (score 7):

Avoid the non-greedy modifier as anything but a performance hint if you can. Using it can lead to "unexpected" results because adding `?` doesn't actually prevent `.*` from matching anything. For example,

```
$ perl -le'print for "XaXbXY" =~ /X(.*?)XY/;'
aXb
```

---

To avoid matching `X`, you can use the following:

```
s/X[^X]*X//g;
```

If `X` is really something larger than one character, you can use the following:

```
s/X(?:(?!X).)*X//g;
```

Comment: interesting... I'll try that. In my case, the X is more than one char. I'll have to decipher ?:(?!X) tho

Comment: @GClaramunt, `(?: )` in regex patterns are like `( )` in Perl. In this case, it indicates that `*` affects `(?!X).` instead of just `.`. `( )` is frequently misused for this purpose.

Comment: @GClaramunt, `(?! )` checks that what follows doesn't match the contained pattern.

Comment: Why do you prefer that?

Comment: @JohnS, Why don't I use `(...).*?x(...)` to prevent `.*` from matching `x`? Because it doesn't. Non-greediness provides a performance hint; it's not for preventing `.*` from matching. Using non-greediness as anything other than a performance hint is a fragile hack.

Comment: Thanks, interesting. Is there any ref explaining it? I googled but didn't find anything.

Comment: The docs clearly say that `?` is the non-greediness modifier. Are you asking of how `(...).*?x(...)` doesn't prevent `.*` from matching `x`? `perl -E'say "abcxdefx123x" =~ /^(.*?)x\d+x/'`

Comment: This is an interesting example, but I would say here `?` prevents `.*` from matching `x\d+x`, (that is `x123x`) not just `x`. Anyway I thinks your point is important when using non-greediness and a good reason to consider using negate instead.