# regexp and find the smallest matching phrase

Tags: regex, grep

Suppose I have a file that includes the line:

> file: "print.exe", name: "David Albertas", address: "New York City"

I want to use grep and regexp that I get the output -

> name: "David Albertas"

and only this output!

I wrote the command:

```
 egrep -o "name: \".*\"" script
```

but I get bigger output than what I expected which is:

> name: "David Albertas", address: "New York City"

This is not good enough. Can you think of a regexp that can help me? For your convenience, the file is attached.

Comment: Try to add a `?` : `egrep -o "name: \".*?\"" script`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure (as in your pattern) the enclosing quotes you might use the negation of the quotes technique:

```
egrep -o 'name: "[^"]*"' INPUT
```

If you want only the name (after `name:`) you might want to use somehting like sed:

```
sed 's/.*name: \("[^"]\+"\).*/\1/' INPUT
```

Or you can use look-around regexps with `grep`.

```
grep -oP '(?<=name: )".*?"' INPUT
```

Comment: thanks. What if I want to get only "David Albertas" without the "name" prefix ? Do you have a regexp for this?

Answer (score 2):

You need a [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) quantifier. Use [`grep` with `P` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3027524/5527985) for *--perl-regexp*.

```
grep -oP "name: \".*?\"" script
```

Comment: thanks. 
What if I want to get only "David Albertas" without the "name" prefix ? Do you have a regexp for this?

Comment: @CrazySynthax You can use a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `grep -oP "(?<=name: )\".*?\"" script`

Comment: @CrazySynthax Or without the double quotes: `grep -oP "(?<=name: \")[^\"]+"`

Comment: or since you use `grep -P` you could use the `\K` regex escape sequence : `grep -oP "name: \K\".*?\"" script` will return only the "name" part