# Bash Pattern Mathcing string.*char

Tags: bash, pattern-matching

I'm trying to match this pattern in grep that takes the form:

`string.*char`

But it doesn't match the char to the first occurrence.

Example:

```
command | grep -o '{id.*}'
```

The output of command is formatted something like:

`*a lot of stuff I don't care about* {id: *comma sep. data*}, {*more data*}`

I want it to output `{id: *comma sep. data*}` not `{id: *comma sep. data*}, {*more data*}`

Comment: Please add the output of `command`, the actual output of `grep` and your expected output. Add this by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: Are `{id` and `}` on the same line? `grep` matches a line at a time.

Comment: @Barmar yes they are on the same line and I'm aware grep only goes line by line. I did forget add -o flag though

Comment: Then your code looks like it should work. Please edit the question with the details requested by Socowi.

Comment: `.*` is greedy, it will match the longest possible string, not the shortest.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027518/how-to-do-a-non-greedy-match-in-grep

Comment: `grep -o '{id[^}]*}`

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar replied, .* is greedy

`grep -o '{id[}^]*}'`

or

`grep -o -P '{id.*?}'`

will work to make it lazy